Type '(Person | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type 'People'
I am getting this typescript error when returning updated state from reducer:
Type '(Person | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type 'People'
reducer.ts:
export type Person = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  phone: number;
  email: string;
  hobbies: string[];
};
export type People = Array<Person>;

type State = { people: People; modal: null | string };
type Action = {
  type: string;
  obj?: Person;
  data?: { id: string; obj: Person };
};

const initState: State = { people: [], modal: null };

export const reducer = (state: State = initState, action: Action): State => {
  if (action.type === "ADD") {
    let newPeople = [...state.people, action?.obj];
    return { ...state, people: newPeople };
  }
return state
}

actions.ts:
import { Person } from "../reducers/reducer";
import { AppDispatch } from "../store";

export const add = (obj: {}) => (dispatch: AppDispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: "ADD", obj });
};

I am trying to update the state in reducer but i am not able to assign people to new People and I am getting these errors:
Type '(Person | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type 'People'.
  Type 'Person | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Person'.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Person'.ts(2322)
reducer.ts(10, 16): The expected type comes from property 'people' which is declared here on type 'State'


action?.obj could be undefined, and you told the compiler the array could only contain Persons. Either don't unconditionally add the action, or change the type of State and People.

okay, so what do i do to solve this problem, sorry complete newbie in typescipt here.

Use the solution by Cory Kramer: only add action.obj to the array if it's not undefined. This is the exact kind of mistake Typescript is supposed to help us all not make anymore :)

It worked. thanks Cory and Jared.

The issue is on this line
let newPeople = [...state.people, action?.obj];

due to the optional chaining action?.obj may be undefined. One fix could be something like
let newPeople = state.people;
if (action.obj !== undefined) { 
  newPeople.push(action.obj);
}

